# Convert .bat to Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Looking for a bit of help here. I have the following batch file that I am looking to convert to powershell. 
What it does is edit a registry entry remotely.
The lines are the following:

```
sc \\FULLCOMPUTERNAME config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb20/nsi
sc \\FULLCOMPUTERNAME config mrxsmb10 start= disabled
```

I am looking to put this into Powershell I guess? Just have these lines be there, and powershell prompt for full computer name, which I would enter then the registry would be updated.
Would it be possible? And if yes, how?
Thanks!

Comment: One thing to remember about powershell is **it's still a shell**, and so many of the batch calls will still work in the equivalent *.ps script... especially if, as we see here, you're just running a couple programs.

Comment: Look at the `Set-Service` cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-3.0. Work with dependencies: https://serverfault.com/a/282118.

Answer (score 0):

To have it prompt for what PC you would just need to save a read line into a variable (lets also get their credentials too):

```
$targetServer = Read-Host;
$cred = Get-Credential;
```

for remote work in powershell you would need to create a remote session and invoke the command.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $targetServer -Credential $cred
```

When you invoke the command, youll pass the session as a parameter:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -InputObject{
    Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\...' -Name 'This Process' -value 00000000
}
```

Comment: Actually credentials shouldn't be requested.
We run this as admin, and I'd like the command to run as-is, and just ask me for the computer name every time.
Would that be possible?

Comment: as long as its powershell, yes. 'Read-Host' prompts the user for input, and "$targetServer =" is assigning their input to a variable. put the variable after config (just like you would the servers name) and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the file extension for this particular script from `.bat` to `.ps1` and it will still just run.

Powershell does have it's own more idiomatic ways to accomplish this, but it's still a shell where you can call other programs, and `sc.exe` is such a program. Since I don't see any other batch constructs (such as command-line arguments) to translate, I believe this script as shown will run unchanged in either environment.

Comment: Sounds good enough, however, how do I make powershell prompt and ask me what the computer name is every time? As I believe just converting this to .ps1 would make it run for 'computername', instead of the actual computer name I have to replace every time in the batch/cmd.

Comment: Except sc is an alias, so make sure it's sc.exe.